# Decimal places to 2 values in Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone help with the following scenario.

In a textfield, i will give input say

```
String input1 = "120.3456";
```

But system will automatically take 2 decimal points and displays "120.35"
Now i will store using getAttribute("value") into a different string say

```
String getValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/....xpath of the text field")).getAttribute("value");
```

How can i validate that my given input value is rounded to 2 decimal points in Selenium Webdriver?
Would be grateful if someone can provide me the best approach. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it simply as below. You'll need to take the `input` and `value` strings and convert them to `double`. You'll need to round `input` and compare to `value`. This returns `true` if the two values are equal, `false` otherwise.

```
String input1 = "120.3456";
double input1Rounded = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(input1) * 100.0) / 100.0;
String value = driver.findElement(locator).getAttribute("value");
double valueRounded = Double.parseDouble(value);
return (input1Rounded == valueRounded);
```

Comment: No. You need to convert everything to decimal radix, e.g. a String, and do the rounding or truncation there. Floating point values don't have decimal places so they cannot be truncated or rounded to them.

Comment: @EJP I'm not following what you are saying. Can you elaborate? How does converting a number to a String help? This code works... have you tried it? It's also all over the web as the example of how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try as below :-

```
String input1="120.3456";

String getValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/....xpath of the text field")).getAttribute("value");

String str = new BigDecimal(input1).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();

return str.equals(getValue)
```

Hope it helps...:)